# Важен ли порядок подключения заголовочных файлов?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В том числе стандартных (iostream, windows.h и т.п.). Если важен, то как сделать так, чтобы  подключать можно было в любом порядке? Или хотя бы откуда я должен знать, в каком порядке из подключать?

Comment: Должен быть неважен. В идеале. А в реальности -- видели сами. Откуда знать -- из рассмотрения этих самых файлов. Но проще найти приемлемый вариант перетасовкой include'ов

Comment: @ололо может вам  лучше какую-нибудь книгу по C++ прочесть?

Comment: @DreamChild, а там найдется ответ на мой вопрос?

Comment: @ололо там найдутся ответы на 90% ваших вопросов. Это я к тому, что язык нужно учить по хорошим учебникам, а не по урывочным вопросам на форумах

Comment: @ололо, например такую: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5600302/

Answer (score 1):

В частном случае, в пределах одного файла в вашем проекте, порядок неважен.

В общем случае, для целого проекта, возможен сценарий, когда ваши собственные заголовочники должны включать друг-друга в каком-то особом порядке.
Всё становится понятнее, если представить, что директива `#include` просит препроцессор поместить всё содержимое указанного файла в то место, где она сама находится. Это работает и для файлов `*.с` или `*.сpp`, а разместить `#include` можно в любом месте - хоть в середине, хоть в конце кода.

Answer (score 0):

В идеале не важен, каждый файлы должен быть самодостаточным, и макросы не должны переопределяться.

Идеал нарушается тем же `<windows.h>`, который при наличии и `<afx.h>` должен идти после `<afx.h>`

Во избежание создания непреднамеренных зависимостей, есть рекомендации:

1. Сначала свои файлы, потом библиотеки, STL в конце
2. В .cpp файлах соотвествующие им .h файлы - в в самом начала
   Эти рекомендации всё же могут не помочь в самодостаточности, особенно если использовать precompiled headers.

Другая распространённая практика - сортировать в алфавитном порядке. Это позволяет легко находить дубликаты.

Вообще с этими .h файлами беда-беда, от которой по идее должны частично спасти модули вместо .h файлов.

Comment: "Сначала свои файлы, потом библиотеки, STL в конце" -- почему так? Делал наоборот всегда

Comment: Чтобы отслеживать зависимости и меньше забывать включать в свои хедеры их пререквезиты

Comment: Не понял. Когда включаешь их после стандартных хедеров, то не отслеживаешь зависимости и/или меньше забываешь, чем когда перед?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2762568/13970074) есть разные мнения, я делаю как в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762626/13970074)  и [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763292/13970074) ответах